# Recreate the 3D outlines of a City street in iOS SceneKit with OSM XML data

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding, openstreetmap, scenekit

What is best strategy to recreate *part* of a street in iOS SceneKit using .osm XML data?

Please assume *part* of a street is offered in the OSM XML data and contains the necessary geopoints with latitude and longitude denoting the Nodes to describe the paths/footprints of 6 buildings (i.e. ground floor plans that line the side of a street).

Specifically, what's the best strategy to convert latitude and longitude Nodes in order to locate these building footprints/polygons on the ground floor in a scene within SceneKit iOS? (i.e. running through position 0,0,0)?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very roughly and briefly, based on my own experience with 3D map rendering:

1. Transform the XML data from lat/long to appropriate coordinates for a 2D map (that is, project it to a plane using a map projection, then apply a 2D affine transform to get it into screen pixel coordinates). Create a 2D map that's wider and taller than the actual screen, because of what's going to happen in step 2:
2. Using a 3D coordinate system with your map vertical (i.e., set all the Z coordinates to zero), rotate the map so that it reclines at an appropriate shallow angle, as if you're in an aeroplane looking down on it; the angle might be 30 degrees from horizontal. To rotate the map you'll need to create a [3D rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). The axis of rotation will be the X axis: that is, the horizontal line that is the bottom border of your 2D map. The rotation is exactly the same as what happens when you rotate your laptop screen away from you.
3. Supply the new 3D coordinates to your rendering system. I haven't used SceneKit but I had a quick look at the documentation and you can use any coordinate system you like, so you will be able to use one that is convenient for the process I have just described: something that uses units the size of a screen pixel at the viewing plane, with Y going upwards, X going right, and Z going away from the viewer.
4. One final caveat: if you want to add extrusions giving a rough approximation of the 3D building shapes (such data is [available in OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_Buildings) for some areas) note that my scheme requires the tops of buildings, and indeed anything above ground level, to have negative Z coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. First, convert Your CLLocationCoordinate2D to a MKMapPoint, which is exactly the same as a CGRect. Second, scale down the MKMapPoint by some arbitrary number so it fits in with how you want it on your scene graph, let's say by 200. Since scenekit's coordinate system is centered at (0,0), you'll need to make sure your location is correct. Then just create your scnvector3's with the x/y of he MKMapPoint, and you will be locked to coordinates.